# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Export: Let user choose save destination?

Tags: ms-access, export, vba

I successfully run TransferSpreadsheet to export an Access query to an Excel file at a specified location:

```
Private Sub cmdExportQuery_Click()
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "trndOTQry", _ 
"\\company.com\root\share\public\D2S\D2S\D2S_Scorecard\Trend OT.xls"
End Sub
```

Given that this is a shared file, I want a dialog to open that allows the user to select whatever save destination he chooses.  I found [this link](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/transferspreadsheet-questions-t1905614.html) with a good solution that references [this article](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm).  When I plug this code into my window:

```
Private Sub cmdExportQuery_Click()
Dim strSaveAsFilter As String
Dim strSaveAsFileName As String
strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strSaveAsFilter, "Excel Files (*.xls)", "*.xls")
strSaveAsFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
OpenFile:=False, _
Filter:=strSaveAsFilter, _
Flags:=ahtOFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT Or ahtOFN_READONLY)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "trndOTQry", _
strSaveAsFileName, , "-1", True
End Sub
```

I get the error `Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined`, it highlights `ahtAddFilterItem` in blue, and highlights `Private Sub cmdExportQuery_Click()` in yellow with a yellow arrow.  I tried making a Public Sub, but nothing happened when I clicked the button.  What must I do to allow the user to choose the save destination when exporting this query to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is additional code that should have also been included.  Check here:

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

I also found this which may be helpful from someone else who had the same error:

"Did you also get the additional code mentioned in the NOTE

Note: This code still requires the GetOpenFileName routine provided by Ken
Getz. Make sure you copy the function from this article.

which sends you to
http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm"

Comment: It was such a large piece of code I just didn't realize it was a necessary precursor.  And I had to spend 30 minutes debugging issues that arose most likely to legacy formatting (i.e. change Global Const to Private Const) as well as fiddle with a few other controls.  Nonetheless, it is up and running